# Unable to use add_flags() function in R properly

Tags: r, package, bioinformatics

I am trying to use the add_flags function on the records of a species obtained using **rgbif**. I am using this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeospatialquality/vignettes/rgbif-synergy.html)

So after loading the data frame onto a variable d as per the instructions I  try to use **add_flags()** and I run into a few errors.

```
> df <- add_flags(d)
Launching API request... done.
Parsing output... done.

=== SUMMARY ===
 records parsed
0 records with coordinates (0 valid)
0 records with country (0 valid)
0 records with scientific name
=== GEOSPATIAL ===
Warning message:
In gq_parse(req) :
  Something went wrong with the call. Got status 500: <html>
  <head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      pre {
        background: #F2F2F2;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server has either erred or is incapable of performing
    the requested operation.</p>
    <pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py&quot;, line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File &quot;/base/data/home/runtimes/python27_experiment/python27_lib/versions/third_party/w [... truncated]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the API was temporarily down, if you try now do you still get the error?

Comment: @nbryans I tried 5 minutes back. Still down.